# Calculating the percentage of a group and still showing the other columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I am trying to get the % of occurrences of my Product for each Country

I aggregated the Volume and ExpectedProfit columns by doing them individually:

**Volume aggregated code:**

```
df = (data1.groupby(['Country','Sector','Product'])['Volume']
      .sum()
      .reset_index(name='Volume'))
```

**ExpectedProfit aggregated code:**

```
grouper = data1.groupby(['Country','Sector','Product'])

df1 = grouper.RealizedPL.sum() + grouper.NetUnrealized.sum()
df1 = df1.reset_index(name="ExpectedProfit")
df1
```

I then **merged** df and df1 together, code:

```
market = pd.merge(df1, df3, left_on=('Country','Sector','Product'), right_on=('Country','Sector','Product'), how='outer')
```

Now I want to calculate the frequency each Product occurs per country.

I have used the following code for the **frequency**:

```
df2 = (data1.groupby(['Country','Sector'])['Product']
     .value_counts(normalize=True)
     .reset_index(name='Products%'))
```

but the issue is that the aggregated Volume and ExpectedProfit disappear.

I really need help and would greatly appreciate it!

You can use the following **sample dataframe** to solve it from scratch:

```
   Country       Sector       Product            Volume    Profit   UnrealizedProfit      
0  Country_1     Sector1      Product_1          50         5            4
1  Country_1     Sector2      Product_2          100        6            3
2  Country_2     Sector1      Product_1          150        3            -1
3  Country_2     Sector2      Product_2          200        -1           5
4  Country_1     Sector1      Product_2          100        7            10
5  Country_2     Sector2      Product_2          200        -3           -1
6  Country_2     Sector1      Product_1          150        2            -1
7  Country_1     Sector2      Product_1          50         5            -3
```

Desired output:

```
   Country       Sector       Product            Product%   Volume    ExpectedProfit        
0  Country_1     Sector1      Product_1          0.138             100        11
1  Country_1     Sector2      Product_2          0.861             200        26
2  Country_2     Sector1      Product_1          0.667             300        3
3  Country_2     Sector2      Product_2          0.333             400        0
```

**NOTE:** Each code works fine individually, but if I merge the Code that gives me the Product% to market dataframe, the % doesn't give me a good result.

**To summarize:** I want the Country, Sector, Product and the aggregated Volume, ExpectedProfit and Product% per Country all displayed on one final dataframe.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: How do you want to agg product? because products are different for different country and sectors...

Comment: Can you. explain a bit how you calculate product% volume and expected profit?

Comment: Product% = Counts Product_1 /total counts Country1. Volume = Sum of volume per country and product. ExpectedProfit = Sum (RealizedPL+NetUnrealized) for each country and product. I have put the code for that in my  question.